# ListView setOnItemClickListener doesn't work on Switch widget

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to catch the click event for a list of Switches

```
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    ArrayAdapter<String> LTRadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_main_view_item, R.id.switch1, values);
    list.setAdapter(LTRadapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Log.w("MiniTasker","w00t " + Integer.toString(pos));
        }
    });
```

i've added android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the ListView but to no avail.

Here's activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_view"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's list_main_view_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Switch"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:tag="0"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your code looks ok... Try to use setOnClickListener and see if it works

Comment: Or onListItemClick, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831801/listview-setonitemclicklistener-in-listfragment-not-working?rq=1

Comment: i've made the items larger, so now the Switch widget covers only half the item, and i get the trigger when i click the empty space below the Switch but not when I click the Switch itself.

Comment: is R.id.main_view referring to your main view or to the list view?

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead

Comment: main_view points to a LinearLayout containing a ListView

Comment: correction: main_view is a ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to extend ArrayAdapter I used in the code and to override getView

```
public class MainListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
...
Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mycontext).getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main_view_item, null);
            assert convertView!=null;
            Switch s = (Switch)convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            assert s!=null;
            s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.w("MiniTasker", "adapter w00t " + Integer.toString(view.getId()));
                }
            });
        }
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you should add an id to your list view in your XML.

Then you can apply that ID to your ListView in your method:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
```

Right now your list reference is pointing at your Linear layout (white space outside your actual ListView). That's why it detects clicks outside the ListView

Comment: oops, i answared you wrong, main_view is the ListView, so it's not it.

Comment: Can you post your XML file?

Comment: Interesting.... Why do you have a Switch wrapped in a RelativeLayout? You don't really need that. Try without it

Comment: found a possible bug!  android:focusable="false" on your relative layout

Comment: i've tried with and without focusable on both the relativelayout and the switch

Comment: removing the relativelayout didn't help :/

Comment: i moved the android:descendantFocusability around too, didn't help as well

Comment: Ok try to add something other than a switch to your list_main_view_item.xml, like TextView (instead of Switch - just for debugging purposes)

Comment: when i add a textview i can catch it's clicks, i can't catch the widget's.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set the clickable attribute to false for switch tag in XML like below, it would work.

```
android:clickable="false"
```

But, I don't see a point in adding a switch in a list view where switch wouldn't be reacting the way we need it to react to click events. If you replace switch with imageView or TextView it will work as those won't react to click events unless specified.

Comment: actually, even with clickable=false it still doesn't work (and the widget is broken as well).

Comment: I wonder why you use switch there, when you could go with image View

Answer (score 0):

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Add this in the XML inside the Switch element.